# Regular expression for splitting a string

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to split a string by using regex, so far I have

```
String[] words = a.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]","").toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
```

And it's almost what I want, but I need to split the text also when there is a newline character in the string (by the way - should I actually use newline or return? What is the actual difference?)

To clarify, my input is:

```
this is a,
sample of
a file.
```

After splitting and doing a routine that sorts the words and counts occurrences of each, I should be getting this:

```
a: 2
file: 1
is: 1
of: 1
sample: 1
this: 1
```

Instead, I get:

```
asample: 1
file: 1
is: 1
ofa: 1
this: 1
```

How should I correct my regular expression to split at newlines as well?

Answer (score 2):

Use `\b[A-Za-z]+\b` regexp to find the word matches.
http://regexr.com/3ae1c

Answer (score 1):

You must change your replaceAll like this:

```
 a.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+"," ")
```

or as suggested by Alexander why not find directly the words (that is more straight to the point)

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a space in your second argument of the replaceAll method and that should work

```
replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]"," ")
```

Or you can make it more efficient and avoid unnecessary spaces in the string returned by the replaceAll method by using the '+' quantifier as suggested by Casimir

Both would work just fine in your case